# Calculating hourly mean using datetime with hour and minutes that aren't separated with a colon

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, datetime, mean

In am working with a pandas data frame. I have a column in my data that shows hours in minutes in this format:

```
    Hour         ALTM         PALT       TMPC       DWPC        RELH  \
0      0  1012.868116  1012.368116  23.556731  19.368497   79.346506   
1     30  1013.142857  1012.642857  23.000000  17.428571   73.714286   
2     35  1012.000000  1011.500000  23.000000  22.000000   94.000000   
3    100  1012.685307  1012.185307  23.251641  19.069231   79.638462   
4    130  1013.333333  1012.833333  24.833333  19.000000   73.166667   
5    200  1012.265487  1011.765487  23.104930  19.143939   80.640506   
6    201  1012.000000  1011.500000  23.000000  21.000000   89.000000   
.
.
.  
68  2330  1013.666667  1013.166667  25.333333  17.500000   63.666667
```

The first two numbers are the hour and the second two are the minutes (except in the cases where the hour is just a single digit). I am trying to take hourly means of all of these variables.

When I convert the Hour column to datetime using this command:

```
hour_goss_mean['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(hour_goss_mean['Hour']).dt.strftime('%H%m')
```

and then do

```
hour_goss_mean['Hour']
```

I get

```
0     0001
1     0001
2     0001
3     0001
4     0001
5     0001
6     0001
```

where the second column is the new Hour column. I am not sure if this is due to the fact that hour and minutes are not separated with a colon in the data. I do not understand how to get the hourly mean.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, first you need to extract the hours and groupby:

```
hours = df['Hour'].astype(int) // 100
df.drop('Hour', axis=1).groupby(hours).mean()
```

Output:

```
             ALTM         PALT       TMPC       DWPC       RELH
Hour                                                           
0     1012.670324  1012.170324  23.185577  19.599023  82.353597
1     1013.009320  1012.509320  24.042487  19.034616  76.402565
2     1012.132743  1011.632743  23.052465  20.071970  84.820253
23    1013.666667  1013.166667  25.333333  17.500000  63.666667
```